# How to use a .mp3 file in java?

Tags: java

I'm using java to try and make an alarm of sorts. I want to input a time and then when it hits zero, play a specific .mp3. The countdown works fine, but when it hits zero and tries to play the mp3, it can't find the file. Advice? I've already searched the site and can't find anything simple enough for me to use (I'm a beginner). Here's what I got so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

   int timer;
   File song = new File("C:/Users/N/Documents/Random/Handies/Proj/Song.mp3");

   timer = 1;
   timer*=1;

   while (timer != 0)
   {
     try
     {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
     timer -= 1;
     System.out.println(timer);
   }  

  if (timer == 0)
    Play(song);    
}

  public static void Play(File song)
  {
    try
    {
      Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
      clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(song));
      clip.start();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
      exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

  }
```

Comment: 'can't find the file' what do you mean by that?

Comment: What framework are you using to play your mp3 file(s)?

Answer (score 0):

With JavaFX you can easily play the MP3 like this:

```
public class Test extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("/path/test.mp3");
        Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }
}
```

I usually find it hard using AudioSystem for this kind of thing.